# Is there any difference between Objects::nonNull and x -> x != null?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, method-reference

Consider the following class:

```
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.function.Predicate;

public class LambdaVsMethodRef {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Predicate<Object> a = Objects::nonNull;
        Predicate<Object> b = x -> x != null;
    }
}
```

The first predicate is created from a method reference and the other a lambda expression.  These predicates have the same behavior (`nonNull`'s body is just `return obj != null;`). The lambda is two characters shorter (perhaps allowing a stream pipeline to fit on one line).

Other than code style, **is there any difference between `Objects::nonNull` and `x -> x != null`?  Put another way, should I prefer one over the other?**

The lambda-dev and lambda-libs-spec-{observers,experts} mailing list messages mentioning `isNull`, `nonNull` and `isNotNull` (early name) didn't address this point.  (I'm surprised no one questioned adding the Objects methods as they are trivially replaceable with a lambda, but on the other hand, so is `Integer::sum`.)

I also looked at the bytecode with `javap`.  The only difference was the method handle passed to the [lambda metafactory bootstrap method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory.html#metafactory-java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles.Lookup-java.lang.String-java.lang.invoke.MethodType-java.lang.invoke.MethodType-java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle-java.lang.invoke.MethodType-):

```
  BootstrapMethods:
0: #16 invokestatic java/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory.metafactory:(Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandle;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;)Ljava/lang/invoke/CallSite;
  Method arguments:
    #17 (Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
    #18 invokestatic java/util/Objects.nonNull:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
    #17 (Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
1: #16 invokestatic java/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory.metafactory:(Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandle;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;)Ljava/lang/invoke/CallSite;
  Method arguments:
    #17 (Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
    #20 invokestatic LambdaVsMethodRef.lambda$main$1:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
    #17 (Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
```

Of course, the metafactory could do different things for method references and lambdas, at the whim of the JVM, so that doesn't prove much.

Comment: Use what you find the clearer and easier to read.

Comment: @JBNizet: Hence "Other than code style, [...]".  I'm wondering if there's some technical difference, possibly due to the innards of lambda or methodref implementation.

Comment: You may want to test performance of each approach to spot a difference. If that's the case, you may read here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/504103/1065197

Comment: No, they both do the exact same thing. The code of nonNull() is `return obj != null;`

Comment: @JBNizet: I know; I looked, and I said the predicates have the same logical behavior.  But that doesn't mean the JVM won't do something different when creating a Predicate instance from a methodref as when from a lambda.

Comment: It's just a matter of DRY. Using the method simply avoids repeating the (admittedly trivial) predicate implementation. Using the method reference will lead to a smaller bytecode, and avoids repetition, thus probably increasing the chance for the nonNull() method to be inlined by the JIT. But anyway, what matters is readability. The hypothetical performance gain is negligible.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

As you noted, the semantics of the lambda `x -> x != null` and the method reference `Objects::nonNull` are virtually identical. I'm hard-pressed to think of any actual observable difference, short of digging into the class using reflection, or something like that.

There is a small space advantage to using the method reference over the lambda. With the lambda, the code of the lambda is compiled into a private static method of the containing class, and the lambda metafactory is then called with a reference to this static method. In the method reference case, the method already exists in the `java.util.Objects` class, so the lambda metafactory is call with a reference to the existing method. This results in a moderate space savings.

Consider these small classes:

```
class LM { // lambda
    static Predicate<Object> a = x -> x != null;
}

class MR { // method reference
    static Predicate<Object> a = Objects::nonNull;
}
```

(Interested readers should run `javap -private -cp classes -c -v <class>` to view detailed differences between the way these are compiled.)

This results in 1,094 bytes for the lambda case and 989 bytes for the method reference case. (Javac 1.8.0_11.) This isn't a huge difference, but if your programs are likely to have large numbers of lambdas like this, you might consider the space savings resulting from using method references.

In addition, it is more likely that a method reference could be JIT-compiled and inlined than the lambda, since the method reference is probably used a lot more. This might result in a tiny performance improvement. It seems unlikely this would make a practical difference, though.

Although you specifically said "Other than code style..." this really is mostly about style. These small methods were specifically added to the APIs so that programmers could use names instead of inline lambdas. This often improves the understandability of the code. Another point is that a method reference often has explicit type information that can help out in difficult type inference cases, such as nested Comparators. (This doesn't really apply to `Objects::nonNull` though.) Adding a cast or explicitly-typed lambda parameters adds a lot of clutter, so in these cases, method references are a clear win.