# Filter Null items in Stream

Tags: java, null, java-8, java-stream

When using a Java Stream, sometimes null values can occur after mapping. Currently when these values need to be omitted, I use:

```
.stream()
.<other operations...>
.filter(element -> element != null)
.<other operations...>
```

For a more functional style a tiny helper method is quickly written:

```
public static <T> boolean nonNull(T entity) {
    return entity != null;
}
```

So that you can use a method reference instead:

```
.stream()
.<other operations...>
.filter(Elements::nonNull)
.<other operations...>
```

I could not find such a jdk method, even though I would suspect they have included one. Is there a different approach here? Or did they omit this for a reason?

Comment: What's wrong with `e -> e != null`?

Comment: Nothing in itself, but I prefer a method reference when this situation occurs in a pipeline using only method references. It felt like a combo breaker.

Comment: Related: [Is there any difference between Objects::nonNull and x -> x != null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25435056/is-there-any-difference-between-objectsnonnull-and-x-x-null)

Comment: As a side note, the type parameter `<T>` is obsolete for your `nonNull` method. It doesn’t change the fact that you can pass any object to it, so you can simply declare the parameter as `Object`.

Comment: @Holger I think you mean "redundant" not "obsolete" but very good point!

Comment: @Mateusz Dymczyk: that depends on whether it had a purpose in an older version of the code which I can’t decide, but yes, “redundant” is likely the better word.

Comment: @Holger It was a leftover of stripping an existing utility stream map method which used T in its return type

Comment: I guess Holger was right then :-)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use [Objects::nonNull](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#nonNull-java.lang.Object-) from the Java8 SDK:

```
.stream()
.<other operations...>
.filter(Objects::nonNull)
.<other operations...>
```

Comment: Can't believe I overlooked that one!

Comment: Both `Objects.isNull()` and `Objects.nonNull()`, were introduced in `1.8`. I believe second method should have been better named as `Objects.isNotNull()`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the  [Objects::nonNull](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#nonNull-java.lang.Object-)

> Returns true if the provided reference is non-null otherwise returns
>   false.

```
.stream()
.<other operations...>
.filter(Objects::nonNull)
.<other operations...>
```